# Jquery setTimeout up my CPU when click for load

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

**This question is not a duplicate of what they put there, moreover it has nothing to do with it since my question is about the possible causes of the cpu firing with the normal onclick event, because otherwise this does not happen to me with this script**

I have this script for update content in section in website for news, etc

```
function read_chat_adm(id_news) {
  var currentFileSize = 0;

  function updateFileContent_adm() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'read_news_adm.php?id_n=' + id_news,
      cache: false,

      success: function(data) {
        var fileSize = data.length;
        if (currentFileSize !== fileSize) {
          $('#news_adm_read').html(data);

          currentFileSize = fileSize;
        }
      },
      complete: function() {
        setTimeout(updateFileContent_adm(), 5000);
      }
    });
  }
  updateFileContent_adm();
}
```

And i call the script using this:

```
<div id="news_adm_read"></div>
<span onclick="read_chat_adm('1235659845');">Load News</span>
```

The scripts works perfectly, load the content when detect new informations, etc, the problem is when i go and make click in the span tag for start load news, in that moment the CPU put in 1 second in 40 % of use, incredible, and i don´t understand why,  because never see this until.

The code is perfect and works and i see finally the problem is with **setTimeout**, because i have the same problem in all brownsers, and really i don´t understand this situation.

Exists some alternative my code or use other function, because try all and continue the high CPU use.

Comment: You didn't tell it to wait 5 seconds before running the function. As written, the settimeout doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: My problem is with the high use of cpu i see increase when use onclick for call function but i dont understand if that´s the problem

Comment: the cpu bit is just a symptom, what's happening is you're spamming the server faster than you intended to because you aren't waiting 5 seconds between requests. Remove the extra `()` within your settimeout

Comment: I don´t understand really, you know the answer for this problem no happend ? or no

Comment: Yea, just remove the `()` from the settimeout. Any remaining cpu problem is unrelated to the code you have provided.

Comment: Can you put the code for eliminate () thank´s

Comment: ??? can you tell me please

Comment: @Jean `setTimeout(updateFileContent_adm, 5000);`